# Audit RDP security layer used for each logon

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, tls, remote-desktop-services, audit

I'm looking for a way to monitor the security layer used when a user log on a windows 2012 R2 server with RDP (SSL or RDP, encryption level).

I haven't found anything useful in "Advanced Audit Policy Configuration" in GPM editor but perhaps I miss something.

Comment: I don't think there is auditing on the RDP session security level - I could be wrong, but shouldn't the approach be to enforce the security level on all servers? If servers accept only secure connections, then there is no need to audit the session level. Or you can show server setting as audit evidence.